# How to can I define scope to HTML block in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very large form in my application page, and I have a `JSON` variable, where I saving all form data in it, and I'm using `controllerAs` expression.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="ctrl.myJSON.name"/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="ctrl.myJSON.old"/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="ctrl.myJSON.address"/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="ctrl.myJSON.email"/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="ctrl.myJSON.phone"/>
    <!-- and many more... -->
</form>
```

How to can I define `myJSON` as the form scope, for no need repeat this variable many time in all fields?

Answer (score 1):

you can use angular extend to copy the json data to $scope. And then, you can use directly:

```
.controller('YourController', function($scope) {

    $scope.readData = function() {
        // replace with your read data function
        var myJSON = { name: 'test' };
        angular.extend($scope, myJSON);
    }

}
```

after that, the variables will work directly:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="name"/>
```

Comment: I think this way maybe dirty scope, and will overflow to another part of HTML block

Comment: Well, it's a bit invasive if the content of JSON could me changed. You can extend to this: angular.extend(this, myJSON) or extend limited properties: angular.extend($scope, { name: myJSON.name, old: myJSON.old })

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the form inside a separate, dedicated controller `FormController` and copy the `myJson` key-value-pairs to its `$scope`.

[This is possible](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) in the later versions of Angular using scope inheritance/nested scopes.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <form ng-controller="FormController">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="name"/>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="old"/>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="address"/>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="email"/>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="phone"/>
        <!-- and many more... -->
    </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // other logic goes here
}]);
myApp.controller('FormController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  // Initialize myJson by loading its data from a service

  angular.extend($scope, myJson);
}]);
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/206redxb/5